# Can i use Sql tag dataSource other page?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jstl

Can iu se Sql tag dataSource other page with application or requst scope?
example: in index.jsp page i have connection:

```
<sql:setDataSource user="root" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" password="123" var="db" scope="application" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/gallery"/>
```

i wont use this connection in my other page
example in gallery page

```
<sql:setDataSource var="d" dataSource="${applicationScope.db}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** it's possible to store the date source in scoped variable and use it in another page **but** is that right thing to do ?

The answer is **No** my advice would be to forget about the `<sql>` tags completely, and to make all your database operations in a servlet. Use RequestDispatcher to dispatch the request to the JSP from the servlet.

From the [official Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html)

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 7-7 are
>   designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production
>   applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in
>   JavaBeans components.